# Change the way Heroku display times in logs

Tags: heroku

A Heroku log would look something like:

```
2021-07-28T13:26:07.189019+00:00 heroku[web.1]:hello world
```

Is it possible to change the time format so that my human brain doesn't need to do math and can understand it directly? Something like `1:26:07 PM 2021/07/28` or something similar would be nice.

While I'm on this topic, this may be a obviously answered question but is it possible for Heroku to not delete my logs when I close the website?

Answer (score 0):

[This is not configurable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-format):

> **Timestamp** - The date and time recorded at the time the log line was produced by the dyno or component. The timestamp is in the format specified by [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2.3), and includes microsecond precision.

However, Heroku logs aren't really meant to be your primary log store. As you have noticed, [they don't store very much data, or retain it very long](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits):

> Logplex is designed for collating and routing log messages, not for storage. It retains the most recent 1,500 lines of your consolidated logs, which expire after 1 week.
>
> For more production-ready persistence of logs, you can add one of the Heroku platform's available [logging add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) to your app. Most of these add-ons offer a free plan to get started.
>
> Alternatively, you can implement your own [log drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) for full control over what happens to your logs.

Many of the third-party log storage options will let you configure how timestamps are displayed. For example, here's [some documentation from Papertrail](https://www.papertrail.com/tour/viewer/seek/) about how to use a more convenient time zone.

I suggest you start by reviewing the [available logging addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging). Many of them have free tiers. Then pick one or two and try them out.